# Deploying a Sharepoint page individually

Tags: sharepoint

Hi
I have a sharepoint site and i have created sharepoint pages in this site using sharepoint designer and created some webparts in these pages and making use of them , when i was moving the things to staging environment i took the back up of my site (.cmp file) and restored there (staging) and everything worked fine, but now i have added a new page to my sharepoint site in dev environment and i want to move this single page to my staging server is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way can be to export your page to your local file system from the dev site, then you open the site on the staging server and import the page into the site from your local copy.

/Erwin

Comment: To clarify - "importing" and "exporting" via downloading the file from the document libraries then manually uploading them.

Comment: Erwin Thank you, it worked for me, but when im moving a page which got updated in dev environment to staging, since it already exist SD is throwing a popup alert asking "file already exist you want to replace it?", when i say yes here it is getting overrided but when i open the code of this page im finding the same old code not updated one, i tried to delete the cache of SD but no luck